# Selected language content is not showing in the site in sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: multilingual

I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 with SXA 1.7. We have a requirement for multisite language so I have created a language here "/sitecore/system/Languages" after this I have changed the language in site grouping and ran a add site language script on the site. After this I took one page and added a Chinese language content.

In Experience editor it is showing the Page title and the content in Chinese language but when I browse the page i am not able to see the Title and Content . Title is still displayed in English.

Can anyone please suggest what I am missing here?

[image]

[image]
Thanks

Comment: if your database is set to web then check if content is published, also try to check in preview mode as well

Comment: Database is set to master and preview mode it is empty @Gaurav Agarwal

Comment: As I don't see any language indication in your url: your default language might be still English - or you could have an English language cookie.

Comment: I specified the language in the url and now its showing the title in Chinese but its not showing the content which i have added in chinese language .Updated the 2nd scrnshot @Gatogordo

Comment: From your printscreen I can see that you are editing the Shared Layout, could you also try to add your component to the Final Layout or check to see if the component is added?

Comment: @CristiVulturar component is already added to the Final layout